# Automatically Get Complete Date dd/mm/YYYY from ddMM

Tags: wpf, xamarin, mvvm, wpf-controls, mvvm-light

Our Date Format is DD/MM/YYYY. If user puts the date and month only, then the app should pick up current year automatically. For Example: If a user puts 0104, then the app should get 01/04/2020. It needs to get the year automatically according to date

If the users selects Date on DatePicker ddmm(ex.0401) then the should automatically get Date in dd/mm/yyyy format(ex.04/01/2020)

```
<DatePicker
            Grid.Column="3"
            x:Name="FinancialYear"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="74,317,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            SelectedDate="{Binding FinancialYear,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy',ValidatesOnDataErrors=False}"
            Uid="none" Width="151"
            PreviewKeyDown="FinancialYear_PreviewKeyDown">
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: You set a string format `StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'` for that

Comment: i have only type ddmm(ex.0401) date picker automatic get string format dd/mm/yyyy(ex.04/01/2020)

Comment: Welcome to SO! What does your C# code behind look like? Could you please share that code

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `StringFormat` of the binding to the `DatePickerTextBox`'s `Text` property to whatever format you want. This works just fine for me:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="FinancialYear">
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd MM', 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: I think You didn`t Understand My Question .    Our Date Format is DD/MM/YYYY . If i will put the date and month only then it should have to pick up current year automatically.   For Example :- if i put 0104 then it should have to get 01/04/2020. Need to get year automatically according to date

Comment: So your accepting one input format only (?) but you want another display format?